# Metrics-Database Number Saving Conventions?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, naming, conventions, database

I want to save metrics (statistics) every day for some processes on my website to display them later in graphs. Example for Metrics might be:

```
FacebookLikes
SiteVisitors
```

Now I want to know how to design the MySQL Table. - Whether I should save the "DeltaFacebookLikes" and "DeltaSiteVisitors" - or whether I should save the absolute numbers which keep growing by each entry:

```
ID    DATE    FACEBOOK_LIKES    SITE_VISITORS
```

The first example (saving the delta values) would be:
The problem here is that I would never have the "total" values - unless I sum them up.

```
1    23.10    33                50
2    24.10    14                80
3    25.10    12                5
4    26.10    28                105
```

The second example (saving the absolute values) would be:
The problem here is that I have the total values, but I would need to subtract v(x) from v(x+1) to archive the actual delta value.

```
1    23.10    33                50
2    24.10    47                130
3    25.10    59                135
4    26.10    87                240
```

What would be the right/wrong way? Is there any wrong way?
Or make both combined sense?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a right answer to this question, but my intuition says to store the incremental numbers on each day.

Storing the cumulative numbers can be quite efficient.  You can readily get the difference between two days, just by looking up two values in the table.  This is particularly efficient, if you have users who are asking about the number of facebook likes for arbitrary time frames.

On the other hand, the individual numbers have certain other advantages:

- If you make a mistake or miss a day's load, then fixing the problem is easier.
- You can more readily calculate standard deviation and variance.
- You can more readily calculate averages by non-contiguous time frames -- such as the Monday average.
- It is easier to do trend analysis.

So, from an analytic perspective, I would find independent daily measurements to be a better choice.  Of course, you can readily translate from one to the other, so the best choice may depend on user access patterns.